# ¿Como puedo cargar un informe de CrystalReports con subinformes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

para contextualizar he logrado crear un reporte de Crystal Reports con un calendario, ya he hecho reportes de CrystalReports con variables a recibir, pero nunca con subinformes. En este caso los subinformes están aplicados a los 7 días de la semana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema surge al cargar el reporte desde un form, ya que pues mando a llamar tanto el form como el mismo crystal reports, aquí pues hago algo similar a lo que comúnmente hago para llamar. Por ejemplo así lo hago comunmente cuando solo tengo que cargar un informe.

```
Reporteador.ConsultaSP s = new Reporteador.ConsultaSP();
                DataSet Ds = s.CheckOp(Miku, Mode);
                RptCheckOperation RDOC = new RptCheckOperation();
                RDOC.SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);

                FormCheckOperation ChO = new FormCheckOperation();
                ChO.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RDOC;

//Esto de aqui es la funcion CheckOp, la cual hace la llamada al StoreProcedure para poder llamar a un Select 
public DataSet CheckOp(string Jo, int Accion)
        {
            var ConnectionString = conexionP.ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand Con = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SELECTCHECKOP]", sql))
                {
                    Con.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Con.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CheckOp", Jo));
                    Con.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Accion", Accion));
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Con);
                    sql.Open();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
                
            }
        }
                
           
                //Esto de aqui es simplemente para abrir el form desde un panel, esto no influye mucho que digamos a pesar de que vean varias lineas de codigo. 
                if (activeForm != null)
                    activeForm.Close();
                activeForm = ChO;
                ChO.TopLevel = false;
                ChO.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                ChO.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                panel4.Controls.Add(ChO);
                ChO.BringToFront();
                ChO.Show();

//Esto es el StoreProcedure, nada complejo en realidad

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECTCHECKOP]
    @CheckOp varchar(40),
    @Accion int
AS
BEGIN
    if @Accion = 1
    begin
        select * from viewcheckoperation where [N° de OT (secundario)] = @CheckOp order by Assembly_Level asc, [N° de OT (secundario)] asc, Sequence asc
    end

    if @Accion = 2
    begin
        select * from viewcheckoperation where [N° de OT Primario] = @CheckOp order by Assembly_Level asc, [N° de OT (secundario)] asc, Sequence asc
    end
END
```

Bueno, esto es la demostración de que realmente se como se carga un reporte con informe, mi problema es cuando quiero cargar uno con subinformes, en este caso los que se muestran en los cuadros grandes son los reportes, los cuales los quiero filtrar con una variable como lo hago en el ejemplo que tengo acá arriba.

Así es como lo tengo según he investigado de como se hace.

//Por lo que vi se tiene que utilizar Subreports, el Ds es reciclado del ejemplo anterior, y el Dr, es uno punto y aparte, pero es bastante sencillo y en este caso es de un informe normal. En este caso quiero utilizar el reciclado 7 veces, si básicamente 1 por cada día de la semana. El problema es que me sigue dando error y quisiera ver si alguien me pude dar el apoyo

```
Reporteador.ConsultaSP R = new Reporteador.ConsultaSP();
                DataSet Dr = R.SelectDate(1);
                Sanae RDOCA = new Sanae();
                //
                RDOCA.Load(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Crystal Report\\HonorariosMedicos\\rptHMAmbGeneral.rpt");
                RDOCA.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports[2].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports[3].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports[4].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports[5].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports[6].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.SetDataSource(Dr.Tables[0]);

                FormProMes Ch1 = new FormProMes();
                Ch1.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RDOCA;



                if (activeForma != null)
                    activeForma.Close();
                activeForma = Ch1;
                Ch1.TopLevel = false;
                Ch1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                Ch1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                panel3.Controls.Add(Ch1);
                Ch1.BringToFront();
                Ch1.Show();
```

Agradecería mucho su apoyo, disculpen si fui algo redundante, pero considero que debia dar mas apoyo de contexto de mi situación.